# Paypal and calculating international shipping?

Tags: paypal

Does anyone have advice on how one can calculate shipping to a foreign country with PayPal? I am developing in PHP.

-JT

Answer (score 1):

PayPal is an online payment processing company, not a shipping company. To calculate shipping costs you'll need to work with the API of a shipping provider. Each provider has their own API:

UPS:
https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US

USPS:
http://www.usps.com/webtools/

FedEx:
http://fedex.com/us/developer/

DHL:
http://www.dhl-usa.com/xml/index.asp

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle shipping is to use the [Instant Update API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECInstantUpdateAPI). Basically, you provide PayPal with a callback (web service) that calculates shipping when users are reviewing payment on PayPal's site.